# Array inside an array during javascript processing

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, arrays

I am trying to process a form using Ajax and have been having a problem with processing check boxes. I thought I could do an array inside an array which would add the checked boxes to the data object but that doesn't seem to be working. It doesn't show up as a part of the object in the console or anything like that. I tried a few variations and nothing was working. This is what it looks like currently:

```
var formData = {
        'fname' : $('input[name=fname]').val(),
        'lname' : $('input[name=lname]').val(),
        'phone' : $('input[name=phone]').val(),
        'email' : $('input[name=email]').val(),
        'sqft'  : $('select[name=sqft]').val(),

        'checked': $('input[name=services[]]:checked').each(function(){
            checked.push($(this).val());
        });
    };
```

I know I could use `serialize()` but honestly I am simply not familiar with processing data from that method. Since I need to process the data with `PHP` I wanted to stick with what I know.

This is the markup for the checkboxes:

```
<div class="checks span6">
 <p>Check which services you are interested in:</p><br>

 <input type="checkbox" name="services[]" value="janitorial"><p>Janitorial</p><br>
 <input type="checkbox" name="services[]" value="window"><p>Window cleaning</p><br>
 <input type="checkbox" name="services[]" value="carpet"><p>Carpet service</p><br>
 <input type="checkbox" name="services[]" value="restroom"><p>Restroom sanitation</p><br>
 <input type="checkbox" name="services[]" value="facility"><p>Facility Maintenance</p><br>
 <input type="checkbox" name="services[]" value="floors"><p>Floor strippin &amp; re-waxing</p><br>
 <input type="checkbox" name="services[]" value="moving"><p>Move in or move out</p><br>
 <input type="checkbox" name="services[]" value="other"><p>Other</p><br>
</div>
```

Comment: javascript aint java

Comment: oops. its really late and i'm really tired haha.

Comment: Please include your checkboxes markup code

Comment: @eignhpants do you really need to put them inside another javascript container? you're going to process this anyway in PHP right? or you're going to use ajax?

Comment: @Ghost its possible you are right but I can't seem to get any of my checkbox data through to the php script. I thought maybe it was related to Ajax (which I am VERY new to using).

Comment: @eignhpants should be fairly straightforward in PHP, depending on the form method, could just be  `$_POST['services']` should contain the selected checkboxes in a form of array, if you use ajax to transport it to PHP, the answer below if correct. +1

Comment: @Ghost the issue was ajax and the below post solved it thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently there is a syntax error in the posted code, extra `;` after closing `)` for the `each` method. You should also escape the `[]` part of the name attribute's value or wrap it with quotes in your selector.  Apart from that you are storing a jQuery object instead of an array of selected values. You can use the `map` method.

```
    'checked': $('input[name="services[]"]:checked').map(function(){
        return this.value;
    }).get()
```

Comment: this worked, thanks a lot. i wasn't aware of the `.map` function. as usual i probably should have check the documentation better.

Answer (score 0):

If you're open to learning new ideas, here's how you could use `.serialize()` -- very straight forward and nothing on the server-side (PHP) needs to be changed:

```
 var formData = $('form').serialize(); //THAT's it!!
```

In your case this would produce the following `query string` -- already URL encoded -- which is what your current data would converted to before `POST`ing:

```
services%5B%5D=janitorial&services%5B%5D=window&services%5B%5D=carpet&services%5B%5D=restroom&services%5B%5D=facility
```

Comment: do i need to parse it in any special way?